# Adapt field to store to database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I have a field `content` that is a json. I would like to store it in database so that my domain class keeps only the 1 field only. (It's more of a brain task ;-)

```
class MyDomain{

   def content

   static constraints = {
        content nullable: false, blank: false, sqlType: "text" // adapter from JSON to String??
    }

def beforeInsert(){
    content = content.toString()
}

def beforeUpdate(){
    content = content.toString()
}

def afterInsert(){
    content = JSON.parse(content) as JSON
}

def afterUpdate(){
    content = JSON.parse(content) as JSON
}

def onLoad(){
    content = JSON.parse(content) as JSON
}

}
```

I want my domain object to expose only `content` so I don't want to use another field like `String contentAsText` because it would be visible outside.

In the whole GORM documentation I haven't found a thing how to manage it. I've tried `beforeValidate()/beforeInsert()` and `onLoad()` methods but no luck...

How can I adapt the value before it gets persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom hibernate `user-type` for `JSONElement` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28655708/607038

In domain class constraints:

```
static constraints = {
   content type: JSONObjectUserType
}
```

User Type Class:

```
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject
import org.hibernate.HibernateException
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes
import org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType

import java.sql.PreparedStatement
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Types

class JSONObjectUserType implements EnhancedUserType, Serializable {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = [Types.VARCHAR]

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return JSONObject.class
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false
        }
        JSONObject zx = (JSONObject) x
        JSONObject zy = (JSONObject) y
        return zx.equals(zy)
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return object.hashCode()
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Object jsonObject = StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names, session, owner)
        if (jsonObject == null) {
            return null
        }
        return new JSONObject((String) jsonObject)
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, null, index, session)
        } else {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) value
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, jsonObject.toString(), index, session)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return cached
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    @Override
    public String toXMLString(Object object) {
        return object.toString()
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromXMLString(String string) {
        return new JSONObject(string)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDomain{

   JSONElement content

   static constraints = {
        content nullable: false, blank: false, sqlType: "text" // adapter from Map to String??
    }

    def setContent(String textContent){
        content = JSON.parse(textContent)
    }
}
```

I had to do 2 things.

1. replace `def content` with `JSON content` so that it gets persisted, see [Grails Domain Constructor is not Groovy Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545108/grails-domain-constructor-is-not-groovy-constructor/43546046)
2. Convert a json string back to json via `def setContent()`.

As `content` is `JSONElement` use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` as concrete classes.