# Grails Domain Constructor is not Groovy Constructor

Tags: grails, groovy, constructor

Executing this peace of code

```
class DefObject{
  String a
  def b
}

def c = new DefObject(a:1, b:2);
```

yields different results in Grails and in Groovy.

**Groovy**

```
assert c.a == 1
assert c.b == 2
```

**Grails Domain Class**

```
assert c.a == 1 
assert c.b == null
```

How can I make Grails Domain to accept a value for `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because in domain classes, only "bindable" properties can be set via the map constructor. You can override whether a property is bindable or not (e.g. the `id` property isn't for security reasons, but if you know what you're doing you can configure it to be).

Untyped properties like `b` are not persistent since GORM/Hibernate has no way of knowing how to store the data if it's just specified with `def` or `Object`. So they're not bindable since they're not persistent, and they're ignored by the customized map constructor.

This is a convenient feature for other reasons, e.g. it allows `new DefObject(params)` to work without complaining about query parameters in the `params` map that don't correspond to properties in the domain class, e.g. `controller` and `action`. Using the Groovy constructor, if you have a value to the map where the key doesn't correspond to a class property, a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` is thrown but these are ignored in domain classes.

Comment: Thanks, Burt, good to know. It's complicating my intention in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544783/adapt-field-to-store-to-database .